# I can't run my code in Terminal in VS code on OSX

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, directory

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run my program, in a variety of ways which I believe should work:

```
drew@Drews-MacBook-Pro Golang % sudo go run .\Golang exercises
Password: <password entered>
no required module provides package .Golang: go.mod file not
    found in current directory or any parent directory:
    see 'go help modules'

drew@Drews-MacBook-Pro Golang % cd /users/drew/Documents/Golang/Golang exercises
cd: string not in pwd: /users/drew/Documents/Golang/Golang

drew@Drews-MacBook-Pro Golang % sudo go .\Golang exercises
Password: <password entered>
go: .Golang: unknown command
Run 'go help' for usage.

drew@Drews-MacBook-Pro Golang % sudo go run .\Golang exercises
Password: <password entered>
no required module provides package .Golang: go.mod file not
    found in current directory or any parent directory:
    see 'go help modules'
```

It seems to not connect to the proper directory, but I am not sure if that is the exact problem. I ran using `sudo` as well and changed the directory, but it was to no avail.

Comment: Drew, I brought the image into the question itself rather than as a link, that's considered better practice here on SO. Forgivable since you're new but it's a good idea to brush up on the editing possibilities as you become more familiar with the site. When entering a question, there's a lot of things above the text entry box that you can click on to explain what you can do.

Comment: @paxdiablo they can't inline images because not enough rep. and they probably shouldn't be using images for this at all. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: @starball: good point. I'm usually less concerned about things that people are unlikely to have to type in for checking (or they're short enough not to matter). But, as you say, it's a good idea anyway, so I've edited the picture content in as text.

Comment: @paxdiablo see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415047/11107541

Comment: Well, I'm not sure we can really complain about things posted as images and, at the same time, people converting them to text. Otherwise, we could be seen as being unfriendly to newbies, and that's a third thing someone may complain about :-) Yes, there are possibilities for errors but the text here is relatively small (I would have baulked at the effort otherwise) and I checked it pretty thoroughly. Even if I'd misspelled something, this particular case would be minimal impact since the cause and error text would still be pretty clear.

Comment: Drew, see the comments to date as well. It would be good if future questions had images only for thing that *needed* to be images (graphics, etc). Screenshots of text would be better posted as text. Not being critical, just trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here.

---

First, OSX is a UNIX-like system, where the path separator is the "normal" slash, `/`.

The backslash is used as an escape character, for things like `\t` (tab) and `\n` (newline).

Since `.` is not one of the special escape characters in this context, the sequence `\.` is just treated as if the `\` wasn't there (so as `.`, which is why it complains about `.Golang`).

---

Second, if you have spaces in file or path names, you have to quote them so the shell treats them as a single argument.

Without that, the a command like

```bash
mkdir /Users/drew/Documents/Golang/Golang exercises
```

will attempt to make the *two* directories `/Users/drew/Documents/Golang/Golang` and `./exercises`, rather than a *single* directory containing a space.

---

Examples of some of the commands in your question, taking *both* those points into consideration, would be:

```bash
sudo go run './Golang exercises'                   # Slash, quote.
cd '/Users/drew/Documents/Golang/Golang exercises' # Quote.
```